# VBA save worksheet as workbook in a specific path

Tags: excel, vba

So i've been working on saving a sheet as a workbook in a specific path. When im pasting the sheet (sheet4) into the new workbook, the first sheet in that new workbook is sheet4. That is fine, but the second sheet, which doesn't need to be there, is named sheet1 and is empty. How can i overwrite sheet1 as the sheet im pasting (sheet4). Or is it possible to delete the sheet1 without a warning popping up?

```
Sub newWorkbook()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Add

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(4).Copy Before:=wb.Sheets(1)
    wb.SaveAs "C:\the path and file"

    Sheets(2).Delete

End Sub
```

Hope someone can help me :)

UPDATE:

So the workbook is closing after saving in the path and works nice. The problem is if there is a file with the same name as the one im trying to save, then i want to overwrite that file in the path. Still hoping its possible to add a date to the file name, which should be the date of the day it has been saved.

Doing it for sheet4:

```
Sub saveFile1()

    Dim PathToSave

    PathToSave = "C:\the path\the file name.xlsm"
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(4).Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=PathToSave, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
    ActiveWorkbook.Close False

End Sub
```

And the same is made for sheet5:

```
Sub saveFile2()

    Dim PathToSave

    PathToSave = "C:\the path\the file name.xlsm"
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(5).Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=PathToSave, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
    ActiveWorkbook.Close False

End Sub
```

Comment: So, do you want copying only `Sheets(4)'?

Comment: I got a workbook where i have 5 sheets. Then i want to save sheet4 and sheet5 as a new workbook, two different. In the first new workbook sheet4 should be the only sheet in that workbook, and in the second new workbook sheet5 should be the only in that workbook :)

Comment: Does the updated code do what you need? Your question did not mention anything about the fifth sheet...

Comment: Just trying it now. And thought of making 2 subs, one for each sheet, but nice if both gets saved in same sub

Comment: Did you test it? Does it do what you need?

Comment: The question where the link is targeting has been deleted...

Comment: @FaneDuru updated the question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69220260/vba-match-rows-in-sheet1-sheet2-and-show-matched-in-sheet3-and-unmatched-in-sh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want saving the fourth and the fifth sheet as a new workbook, please use the next code:

```
Sub newWorkbook()
 Dim PathToSave1 As String, PathToSave2 As String, wb As Workbook, arrSh(), shN, i As Long
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    arrSh = Array(wb.Sheets(4).Name, wb.Sheets(5).Name)
    PathToSave1 = ThisWorkbook.path & "\"  'use here the path you need
    PathToSave2 = ThisWorkbook.path & "\testFolder\"
    For Each shN In arrSh
        wb.Sheets(shN).Copy
         i = i + 1
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
         ActiveWorkbook.saveas FileName:=IIf(i = 1, PathToSave1, PathToSave2) & _
                 shN & "_" & Format(Date, "dd_mm_yyyy") & ".xlsm", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
         ActiveWorkbook.Close False
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: @Anonymous Updated the above code to save sheets 4 and 5, using their name as workbook name. If you want it to add the current date, it is possible, but not in that format ("\" is illegal character in naming a file...). Adapted it to return the current date in a format using underscore as separator. Is it what you need?

Comment: @Anonymous Please, test the adapted code and send some feedback.

Comment: @Anonymous I adapted the code to overwrite the workbook, if existing. And saves the workbook as you try (.xlsm)... Doesn't it work as you need? But, be careful to end any of the used paths **in "\"**...

Comment: @Anonymous Now, we here when somebody answer our question, tick the code left side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for a similar issue will know that the supplied solution works... I will also delete my comments.

Answer (score 0):

### Copy a Single Sheet to a New Workbook

- The following covers some (the ones I could think of) of the surprises you may encounter when copying a single sheet to a new workbook. Some of them are more or less ridiculous yet valid.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub SheetToWorkbookTEST()
    Const ProcName As String = "SheetToWorkbookTEST"
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    Const dFolderPath As String = "C:\Test\"
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim sh As Object: Set sh = ActiveSheet ' wb.Sheets("Sheet4")
    SheetToWorkbook sh, dFolderPath, "File", Date

ProcExit:
    Exit Sub
ClearError:
    MsgBox "'" & ProcName & "': Unexpected Error!" & vbLf _
        & "    " & "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf _
        & "        " & Err.Description, vbCritical, ProcName
    Resume ProcExit
End Sub

Sub SheetToWorkbook( _
        ByVal SourcSheet As Object, _
        ByVal FolderPath As String, _
        ByVal FilePattern As String, _
        ByVal FileDate As Date, _
        Optional ByVal DateFormat As String = "yyyymmdd", _
        Optional ByVal PatternDateSeparator As String = " - ", _
        Optional ByVal SheetName As String = "Sheet1")
    Const ProcName As String = "SheetToWorkbook"
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    Dim pTitle As String: pTitle = "Sheet to Workbook"
    
    If SourcSheet Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No sheet (""Nothing"").", _
            vbCritical, pTitle
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    If TypeName(SourcSheet) <> "Worksheet" Then
        If TypeName(SourcSheet) <> "Chart" Then
            MsgBox "The first argument has to be a sheet object " _
                & "(""Worksheet"" or ""Chart""), yet you have chosen " _
                & "an object of type """ & TypeName(SourcSheet) & """.", _
                vbCritical, pTitle
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
    'Debug.Print TypeName(SourcSheet)
    
    If Len(Dir(FolderPath, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "The folder '" & FolderPath & "' does not exist.", _
            vbCritical, pTitle
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim aSep As String: aSep = Application.PathSeparator
    Dim dFolderPath As String
    If Right(FolderPath, 1) = aSep Then
        dFolderPath = FolderPath
    Else
        dFolderPath = FolderPath & aSep
    End If
    'Debug.Print dFolderPath
    
    Dim dFilePath As String
    dFilePath = dFolderPath & FilePattern & PatternDateSeparator _
        & Format(FileDate, DateFormat) & ".xlsx"
    'Debug.Print dFilePath
    
    If SourcSheet.Visible <> xlSheetVisible Then
        MsgBox "The sheet '" & SourcSheet.Name & "' is not visible. " & vbLf _
            & "You can export a single sheet to a new workbook " _
            & "only if it is visible.", _
            vbCritical, pTitle
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    SourcSheet.Copy
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = ActiveWorkbook
    Dim dsh As Object: Set dsh = dwb.Sheets(1)
    If dsh.Name <> SheetName Then
        dsh.Name = SheetName
    End If
    
    Dim SaveErrNum As Long
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' save without confirmation
    On Error Resume Next
    dwb.SaveAs dFilePath, xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    SaveErrNum = Err.Number
    On Error GoTo ClearError ' instead of 'On Error Goto 0'
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    dwb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    If SaveErrNum <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "The file could not be saved as" _
            & vbLf & """" & dFilePath & """" & vbLf _
            & "Make sure the file name is valid.", _
            vbCritical, pTitle
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim msg As Long
    msg = MsgBox("Sheet '" & SourcSheet.Name & "' exported to workbook '" _
        & dFilePath & "'." & vbLf & "Do you want to browse its location?", _
        vbInformation + vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2, pTitle)
    If msg = vbYes Then
        SourcSheet.Parent.FollowHyperlink dFolderPath
    End If
    
ProcExit:
    Exit Sub
ClearError:
    MsgBox "'" & ProcName & "': Unexpected Error!" & vbLf _
        & "    " & "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf _
        & "        " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! And great with all the comments, helps a lot